# Scala web :: lazy val scope/lifetime

Tags: scala, servlets, scope, request, lazy-evaluation

In a Scala web application, is lazy val scoped to the lifetime of the application server, or request scoped?

I assume it is per request, but have not been able to find a definitive answer, thus the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lazy` is a Scala feature, not related to web application programming. It means: *evaluate only once on first access*. If the variable is part of an object created per request, it will be lazily evaluated once per every request.

If it is declared inside application-wide class (or `object`), once evaluated it will keep its value as long as the class is loaded (so probably the WAR lifetime).

Comment: yes, I understand the evaluate once bit ;-) when you say, "if the variable is part of an object created per request", that implies that on ANY new object creation, the lazy property will be evaluated once (so if I new up 10 instances of a class and access lazy foo on each instance, I'll have incurred the overhead of lazy 10X)

Comment: How does this relate to Scala singleton Objects, btw? There is no object instance created, so here it's always, access once and future accesses incur no lazy overhead I assume.

Comment: @virtualeyes: yes, `lazy` is bound to an object instance so if you create 10 objects and access `lazy` property of each of them, it will be evaluated once *per every object*. WRT `object` classes (singletons) - there is only a single instance, thus `lazy` is evaluated once per that class (per `ClassLoader`).

Comment: got it, none of the threads I ran across really nailed the scoping issue like you have done here, thanks!