# Scala statement caching with lazy val in servlet environment

Tags: scala, caching, lazy-evaluation

**EDIT**
RTFM, new to the JVM, made the blundering assumption that the servlet container (Jetty in this case) creates a new servlet instance per request: totally wrong.

So, the question below is moot and the above affirms the fact that lazy vals are indeed "forever" (or as long as the instance in which the lazy val is defined continues to exist)

**ORIGINAL**
As I [now understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025567/scala-web-lazy-val-scope-lifetime), in a basic servlet environment we start with a clean slate per HttpRequest.

The implication is that *lazy val overhead is incurred anew on each request*.

A particular issue that concerns me is database query statement caching (via lazy val) and whether or not this incurs an unnecessary performance penalty; i.e. what is the point of caching a query statement on the application server when it lives and dies with each request?

Yes, with connection pooling one can cache query statements independent of request scope, big plus; however, that does not solve the problem that on each request one's ORM/JDBC-Wrapper is going to go through the relatively expensive operation of generating a query statement, cached or not.

So the question is: in a servlet environment is query caching more hindrance than help? (I am using ScalaQuery which caches queries via lazy val)

The only case where it would seem of benefit is when you would call a given query multiple times in the same request, but that is something I rarely if ever do (mostly just run a query for a Foo or List[Foo] *one time per request*)

Comment: BTW could you add logging and see whether the lazy val is recalculated anew with each request?

Comment: moot point, see edit, I was completely wrong re: new servlet instance per request.